# extremal functions and extreme points

Tags: complex-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

A(D) :analytic functions on the unit disk form a locally convex tvs with the
topology of uniform convergence on compact sets.Let F be a convex subset of
A(D) which is also compact and J be a complex linear functional defined on F .

Then the real part of J attains its extremum at an extreme point of F??

Or is it necessary that J be also continuous for the conclusion to hold?

thanks..

Comment: If $J$ isn't continuous, it may be unbounded on $F$.

Comment: Ok , with J being cont. is the conclusion true?

Comment: With continuous $J$, the extrema are attained at extreme points. With discontinuous $J$, that may be the case [for example if $F$ is contained in a finite-dimensional subspace, then the restriction of $J$ to that subspace is continuous], but it also may be that $J$ has no extrema on $F$ then.